# Converting polygon in grid points for each grid of 100m*100m in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, polygon, point, convert, library

I want to convert my polygon layers into point layer where I will have a point for each grid of 100m *100m grid for entire polygon layers using PyQGIS ?

I don't know any library function for grid creation and way to extract single point from the gird Point may be centroid of grid.

That's why I haven't provided any code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

In the QGIS documentation, [Convert polygon/line vertices to points](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/saga/shapes_polygons/convertpolygonlineverticestopoints.html)

it provides this option to convert polygons to points

> Description
>   Converts the line or polygon vertices into points.

Parameters
Shapes [vector: any]
Layer to process.
Outputs
Points [vector]
The resulting layer.

Console usage  (here is the script)

`processing.runalg('saga:convertpolygonlineverticestopoints', shapes, points)`

Comment: But how to add 100m distance for each point condition i.e. Each grid of 100m*100m

Comment: Could you edit this question to just ask about converting polygons and vertices into points, and ask a different question about grid creation. GIS SE, like to have one question per post to make it easier for searching and answer for the community.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the centroid point of each polygon one option would be to the following:

1. You'll first need to get the layer object, once you have that then loop through each feature using `layer.getFeatures()` method (keyword web search "pyqgis vector layer")
2. Once you have the feature object you may use the  `feature.geometry().centroid().asPoint()` which will return the x/y coordinate (keyword web search "pyqgis get layer features")
3. Once you have the x/y coordinate you may then create a new point layer and write the x/y values to that layer thus creating a centroid point layer (keyword web search "pyqgis create point layer AND pyqgis add point features to point layefr")